# Two apparently similar functions give a different result. Why?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am using `Rcpp` to integrate a piece of `C++` code in `R`. I am implementing a function in `C++` in two ways:

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double rhobiweight(double x,double k = 2.0){
  double rho = 1.0;
  if(abs(x)<k){
    rho = 1.0-pow((1.0-pow(x/k,2)),3);
  }
  return rho/Erho(k) ;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double rhobiweight2(double x,double k = 2.0){
  double rho = 1.0-pow((1.0-pow(x/k,2)),3);
  if(abs(x)>k){
    rho = 1.0;
  }
  return rho/Erho(k) ;
}
```

If the `x`-value is between 2 and 3, I get different results of these functions. I can't figure out why.

```
> set.seed(1)
> x = 3*rnorm(10^5)
> c = x
>   c2 = x
>   for(i in 1:length(x)){
+     c[i] = rhobiweight(x[i])
+     c2[i] = rhobiweight2(x[i])
+   }
>   print(sum(c-c2))
[1] -18564.31
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from your `if` statement inside the function. The negative of `<` is `>=`. so you should either replace `<` with `<=` in one function or `>` with `>=` in the other, depending on the expected behaviour.

Your problem happens for value between 2.0 and 2.9 inclusive because the `abs(int)` will always return `2` for this range.

`abs(x)` takes an `int` an return an `int`. Your `double x` is implicitly conversion to an `int` in your case.

Comment: What is the `abs()` for doubles? If do a quick google search I get that `abs` should also work for doubles: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/abs/ .

Comment: @Ruben Even better, use the C++ `std::abs` instead of the old C `abs` and `fabs`, it is overloaded to do the right thing for any input.